# how to delete folder from google cloud vm

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have uploaded a laravel project on google cloud VM. Everything is fine except one thing.
Like I have to delete a directory from the laravel. But it is not working.
On the local server xamp it working fine.

```
Storage::disk('public')->deleteDirectory('uploads/'.$video_folder_name.'/'.$category_folder_name.'/'.$videoupload->unique_number);
```

All the name with $symbol is a variable, which holds a directory value name. The directory has permission with "755". and the owner/group is : www-data www-data

Comment: Do you have an error? Do you use a container or something immutable?

Comment: The problem is solved. Just I restarted my VM again and it works. I spent lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a directory from your Laravel project hosted on a Google Cloud VM, you can use the File facade instead of the Storage facade, especially if you're dealing with directories in the project's file system. Here's how you can do it:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$directoryPath = public_path('uploads/' . $video_folder_name . '/' . 
$category_folder_name . '/' . $videoupload->unique_number);

if (File::exists($directoryPath)) {
    File::deleteDirectory($directoryPath);
    return "Directory deleted successfully.";
} else {
    return "Directory does not exist.";
}
```

In this code:

`public_path()` function provides the full path to the public directory of your Laravel project.
`File::exists()` is used to check if the directory exists.
`File::deleteDirectory()` is used to delete the directory and all its contents recursively.

Ensure that the PHP process running on your Google Cloud VM has sufficient permissions to delete the directory and its contents. If you encounter permission issues, you may need to adjust the ownership and permissions of the directory or grant appropriate permissions to the PHP process user.